# Photo & video viewer similar to Android's Gallery app

Tags: nautilus, video, photo-management

Are there any Ubuntu programs that allow us to view a folder's videos and photos in one integrated viewer in the same way that Android's Gallery app functions?

With Nautilus I have to browse the photos separately, and then browse the videos in a separate video application. However, since videos are often taken at the same time as the photos, I would like to be able to view them all in sequence.

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu's own Shotwell application can display both pictures and videos. Load pictures as normal. Use the "Import from folder" to include your Videos folder... but don't choose to copy the video files, choose import in place.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using VLC. You can find it in the repositories. You can add Images using the menu entry: Media -> Open Multiple Files.

You can use shortcuts to play the next item (video or image): CTRL + Right Arrow.

You can change the duration of an image being shown following the instructions that you can find here: https://www.vlchelp.com/image-slideshow-photo-view/